# Can the query be Improved as it is going for timeout exception

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-update

How Can I improve my Query as it is going to timeout exception. Can somebody help me to improve the query ...???

```
UPDATE pdtdeliveryTable p  SET p.OrderID = IFNULL
( 
   (SELECT OrderID from OrderTable o where o.DiagramID=p.DiagramID AND o.DeliveryDate=
   (
        Select min(o2.DeliveryDate) from OrderTable o2 where o2.DiagramId=o.DiagramID Order by o2.DeliveryDate
   )Limit 1),0
)
where p.OrderID=0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE pdtdeliveryTable p  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT o.DiagramID, o.OrderID FROM OrderTable o 
                 INNER JOIN ( SELECT DiagramID, MIN(DeliveryDate) DeliveryDate 
                              FROM OrderTable GROUP BY DiagramID
                            ) AS A ON o.DiagramID = A.DiagramID AND o.DeliveryDate = A.DeliveryDate 
               ) AS A ON A.DiagramID = p.DiagramID
SET p.OrderID = IFNULL(A.OrderID, 0);
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE pdtdeliveryTable p  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT DiagramID, OrderID 
                  FROM (SELECT DiagramID, OrderID, DeliveryDate FROM OrderTable ORDER BY DiagramID, DeliveryDate) AS A 
                  GROUP BY DiagramID 
                ) AS A ON p.DiagramID = A.DiagramID 
SET p.OrderID = IFNULL(A.OrderID, 0);
```

Comment: @Sarharsh But the query not conidering the minimum DeliveryDate its taking the topmost value for the second query.